# Update Tableview via Notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

**How do I get a table view to update via NSNotification via Push Notifications?**

When my app receives a notification, via the App Delegate's `- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo` method, and the app is currently already running, I update the data (stored via Core Data)

An alert view pops up, and once it is dismissed, I call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateConversations" object:nil];
```

In the table view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //some setup code removed
    _someData = [[GGGroups findAllSortedBy:@"lastUpdated" ascending:NO withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", [GGUser currentUser]]] mutableCopy];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData:) name:@"updateConversations" object:nil];
}

- (void)updateData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Updated those conversations");
    });
}
```

I have tried adding and removing the dispatch_async main queue blocks.

It always reaches the updateData method *(I can see the NSLog)*, the tableview itself never gets updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Update

More code as requested.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_someData count];

}
```

Also each table view cell is configured to an index of _someData.

The appDelegate updates the GGGroups core data structure, so the tableview should accordingly update, but this is not happening, for reasons unknown to me thus far.

Comment: NSLog happens, right?

Comment: Are you sure that you linked tableView properly in IB?

Comment: Show how you populate your table.

Comment: `reloadData` will trigger calls to `UITableViewDataSource` methods. Show the code of those methods. Do they even get called?

Comment: @Undo NSLog does happen

Comment: @Pei I don't use IB, it's all done programatically

Comment: Try adding breakpoints to the datasource methods, like @DanielMartín said.

Comment: @DanielMartín  I have updated the question with more info

Comment: If you break inside `updateData:`, what thread are you on?

Comment: @sjwarner At the moment, my heroku server seems to be having troubles, so my push notifications are coming through, I will check this whenever it starts working again (hopefully soon)

Comment: @sjwarner I checked it now, it is on the main thread on updateData

Comment: If you can guarantee that `updateData` will only ever be called on the main thread, then you don't need to use GCD - get rid of `dispatch_async` and just call `reloadData`.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using Core Data, but you don't actually seem to be observing the changes there (like by using a fetched results controller). You are setting up `_someData` but not updating it when the model changes.

Try updating the data used to fill the table view when you receive the notification:

```
- (void)updateData:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _someData = [[GGGroups findAllSortedBy:@"lastUpdated" ascending:NO withPredicate:[NSPredicate             predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", [GGUser currentUser]]] mutableCopy];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Updated those conversations");
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it just blanks out the entire tableView for some reason

Comment: Which suggests the problem is really with findAllSortedBy or GGUser currentUser...

Comment: my heroku server is working again, so I will see what's up with it by using a breakpoint, findAllSortedby is probably correct though since it is a part of the MagicalRecord CoreData framework on GitHub

Comment: when I do this, _someData becomes empty, however this exact same method works in viewDidLoad, why does it not work here in updateData?

Comment: Suggests that the objects in the model aren't associated with the currentUser. Remove the predicate and breakpoint after the fetch to verify that the managed objects have all the data you expect.

Comment: Interesting, now I actually get updates, however I get multiple versions of a Group, i.e.,  the group at 5pm, the group at 4pm, the group at 3pm, etc.

Comment: When I check my sql database, only 2 Groups popup, but with this method multiple versions of these groups are added to the tableview